# Reduce page load times Prestashop 1.7

Tags: optimization, pagespeed, prestashop-1.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ9PJ.png)

Help reduce page load times Prestashop 1.7
Very low speed

Answer (score 0):

You have to look in more detail at the modules that are loaded, I think that one of them slows down your shop.

Regards

Comment: How to find out which module is slowing down?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what is there when you click on initcontent? from the rest of the debug page? or send an url?

Comment: https://kupit-kuhni-nedorogo.ru/kukhnya-bazis-linewood/kukhnya-bazis-linewood-08#/53-varianty_cvetov_fasada-eboni_temnyj_mokko_sl/50-varianty_cvetov_korpusa-eboni_svetlyj_sl

Comment: When turn on define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Here is a page with debug 
https://kupit-kuhni-nedorogo.ru/kukhnya-bazis-nicole-mix/kukhnya-bazis-nicole-mix-01#/80-varianty_cvetov_fasada-dub_bordolino_ldsp_slnm/81-varianty_cvetov_korpusa-belyj_slnm

Comment: try off module : sirv

Comment: Disconnected, it still loads slowly